# Is there any property in CSS/HTML similar to "line-height", that can be applied to div tags?

Tags: html, css

I tried using the "line-height" property to increase the space between two text boxes but it applies only for text.

SO, is there any other CSS property that can be used to increase the vertical spacing between two divisions ("div"s)??

Comment: You shouldn't be using line-height for that. That's what margin is for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use margin to define the space between the divisions:

CSS:

```
.myDiv { margin: 5px 0; }
```

HTML

```
<div class="myDiv">first</div>
<div class="myDiv">second</div>
```

This will give them a `5px` top and bottom margin. The distance between the divisions will be the largest value for margin for any of them, which is `5px` in this case.

You can specify `margin-top` and `margin-bottom` separately if you want more control. For example zero top margin and `5px` bottom margin:

```
.myDiv { margin: 0 0 5px 0; }
```

which is the same as:

```
.myDiv {
  margin-top: 0;
  margin-right: 0;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  margin-left: 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I feel stupid ;)

BTW, its not "top-margin", its "margin-top". Just a small correction!

Answer (score 2):

look at css margin

http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_margin.asp

Answer (score 1):

```
classname
{
margin-top:10px; // as you wish
}
```

Comment: I'd rather go with margin-top:5px; margin-bottom:5px; to ensure that the boxes are centered.

Answer (score 1):

The space defined outside the box is the `margin`.

It's worth taking some time to understand the shorthand notation:

```
.box {margin: 5px;} /* 5px all sides */
.box {margin: 5px 10px;} /* 5px top and bottom, 10px left and right */
.box {margin: 5px 10px 15px;} /* 5px top, 10px left and right, 15px bottom */
.box {margin: 5px 10px 15px 20px;} /* 5px top, 10px right, 15px bottom, 20px left */
```

Comment: You're welcome, and welcome to Stack Overflow. If you found an answer helpful, you should mark it as correct.